# making dynamic defined constants php

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

look at this syntax of variable name modifying:

```
${'a' . 'b'} = 'hello there';
echo $ab;
```

this returns `"hello there"`

But i want do declare defined variables dynamical.

```
$error_code = $_GET[error_code]; //for example: 404
define(E404, 'Not found');
echo E{$error_code};
```

It return error, i want to generate `E404` dynamical on php codes and get its value.
I have no idea what the syntax or the technique I'm looking for is here, which makes it hard to research.

Comment: You are looking for arrays, that will make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call [constant()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.constant.php) to retrieve the value of a constant from a string. Your example should look like:

```
$error_code = 404;
define('E404', 'Not found');
echo constant("E{$error_code}");
```

and it will display `Not found`.

Comment: Amazing! thought it wasn't even possible to dynamically feed `SORT_ASC` , `SORT_DESC` flags to array functions but then glad I found this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $ErrorCode = $_GET['error_code']; // Where error_code = 404
    $Errors = array(); // here we are creating a new array.
    $Errors[$ErrorCode] = "Whatever"; // here we are setting a key of the new array, with the keys name being equal to the $ErrorCode Variable

    print_r($Errors); // Would return Array( [404] => Whatever);

    echo $Errors["404"]; // Would return Whatever

?>
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Well Php has a feature called variable variables. See this link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php. It allows a variable name to be assigned to a variable.